# I want to display my events scrolling horizontally in events date sequence on my wordpress website

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am working on the wordpress site.(visitingkells.ie) where i am using the Events Manager plugin.By Marcus Sykes .to add the events section to my site on homepage. Now all i wanted was to display these events in carousel in scrolling way so for that I installed hopos slider wordpress plugin. so now I go my all the events in the scrolling way horizontally. But now the main problem is that I want all these events to display in sequence wise Like if one event is of 13 sep 2014 , next events of 14 sep,next 18 sep 2014 so that it displays in the sequential order to the customers when they visit on the site. so i did this setting in my event plugin

Default event archive ordering
When Events Manager displays lists of events the default behaviour is ordering by start date in ascending order. To change this, modify the values above.
Event archives scope

but still the problem is that hopos slider plugin either displays the events based the date it has been added or modified or based on the ID...it does not shows on the base of the Events date mentioned events manager plugin now the problem is that my client want it to be display in horizontal scrolling as it is displaying. I dont what to do now. Please help me on this Either tell me the other plugin with same functionality like hopos slider or tell me how to fix this problem.

The code I am using in php file to display this carousel is....

```
                 <?php echo do_shortcode("[hopos id='1']"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well no one did answered my question but i did found the solution for it... it took me hard time to find the solution ... so i though i should share it for the others.

so I am using the event manager plugin. so i figured they provide their own shortcodes to display events like to display events thumbnails they have different code and to display.... event list they have different shortcode ... but what i did is combined all of them to display it in like a box . See it how :-

I created a widget and used it in the shortcode to use it in the php file..

and this is my widget which i kept in sidebar which i am not using in my wordpress..

```
   <div><ul style="width:152px;height:260px;float:left;text-decoration:none;list-style:none;white-space: normal;position:relative;border: double 4px #ccc;
                 margin: 0px 15px 0px 0px;
                 padding: 2px 0px 36px 11px;
                 background-color: #000;"><li ">#_EVENTIMAGE{200,150}</li><br/>
                <li>#_EVENTLINK</li><br/><li>#_EVENTDATES</li><br/><li>#_LOCATIONTOWN</li>
                <li>#_EVENTEXCERPT{5,...}</li></ul></div>


       // this is the php code  :-

        <div style="width: 600px;height:300 px;background-color: rgb(247, 248, 248);left:0; right:0;top:0;bottom:0;margin:auto;max-width:100%;max-height:100%;overflow:auto;position: static;"><h2 style="padding-top:5px;"align="center">EVENTS</h2>
            <hr/ bgcolor="black">
                <marquee scrollamount="4" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
                <div class="marquee0" style="overflow: hidden; style=" width:="" double="">

                    <div style="width:4000px;" ><div><?php echo do_shortcode("[widget id='em_widget-3']"); ?></div></div>
                </div>
            </marquee>
            <div ></div>
```

so guys enjoy and let me know about your views.